# implementacion de ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android

Quiero implementar PROGRESSDIALOG pero no me funciona alguien me puede ayudar y decirme que hago mal.
Aqui el procedimiento donde lo quiero monstrar!

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registrando Datos");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.ItemSincro) {

        if (!CompruebaConexion(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No se ha podido establecer conexion con internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{

            int CantDatos=recyclerS.getAdapter().getItemCount();//MOSTARNDO CANTIDAD DE DATOS DEL RECYCLER
            int contador = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < CantDatos;i++){

                SincronizarDatos(
                        DateList.get(contador).getNombre(),
                        DateList.get(contador).getApellido(),
                        DateList.get(contador).getEdad(),
                        DateList.get(contador).getGenero(),
                        DateList.get(contador).getDeporte(),
                        "sincronizado"
                        );
                contador++;
            }
            ActualizarEstado();
            ListarDatosSincro();
            AdaptadorRecy Radapter = new AdaptadorRecy(DateList);
            recyclerS.setAdapter(Radapter);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"REGISTROS CARGADOS CORRECTAMENTE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: Cual es el error que te sale?

Comment: no se muestra el progressdialog cuando hago click en el boton!

Comment: tus funciones de ActualizarEstado(); ListarDatosSincro();, sincronizarDatos que hacen? tu pantalla se bloquea durante unos instantes cuando estas en esa pantalla?

Comment: ActualizarEstado(), es un procedimiento que solo actualiza una columna de mi base de datos SQLite

ListarDatosSincro(), es un procedimiento que captura los datos del SQLite almacenando en Arraylist para luego mostrarlos en un recyclerview con cardview

SincronizarDatos(), lee todos los datos del Recyclerview para luego subirlos a mi base de datos SQLServer!

Comment: porfavor explicar que es tu idea ?

Comment: solo quisiera que me ayudes como mostrar un progressdialog al hacer click en el boton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me parece que el progressDialog no se muestra porque la tarea se lleva a cabo con demasiada rapidez o porque estas haciendo la carga de datos en el hilo principal ... lo he probado y si efectuas la tarea en otro hilo que no sea el Main y al terminar recien llamas al metodo dismiss() funciona.

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private void onButtonClicked(){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("registrando datos");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
    tarea = new MiTareaAsincrona();
    tarea.execute();
}

private class MiTareaAsincrona extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            cargarDatos();
        }

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result)
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

pd: el progressDialog ya es obsoleto, te recomiendo que busques otras alternativas.

Comment: Genial muchas gracias....esto si funcionó!!!